# RAM Impact on Oracle database operations

Tags: oracle, memory

We are seeing drastic change in the amount of time taken for db operations depending on ram size.

The same content when inserted into a db running on a 4gb ram machine takes about 600% more than into a db running on a 16gb ram machine. The inserts are made through jdbc. Both the db machines were 64 bit machines and both were enterprise editions of db.

Interesting thing is that the memory consumption for the db running on 4gb machine never goes above 50-60% of the total capacity - so we do not understand why this difference. Is there any explanation for this behavior or some more pointers to look into this?

Comment: duplicating question from stack overflow - as it was suggested this is better suited.

Comment: if you'll register your account you'll get better notification, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Praveen,

Oracle provides a lot of functionality to enable you to trace individual sessions (with waits and binds) or statements. You don't list the version in use, but most probably you can trace the inserts using DBMS_MONITOR package introduced in 10g. In 11g and if you have the relevant management pack licensed you could also use Real Time SQL Monitoring. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/instance_tune.htm#CACGEEIF If you take this approach, of tracing the problematic SQL then you can know for certain where the time is going. The most common cause by the way for slow inserts is nothing to do with RAM and everything to do with the number of indexes on the table.

Comment: Yup even i guessed the indices were causing an issue and removed them before running the inserts - the difference was still huge.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not using all the memory, the possibilities are:

1. The inserts do not need more memory and the performance difference is caused by another difference between the systems.  This could be anything from database initialization parameters, to other database activity, to storage differences, to any number of other differences.
2. The inserts benefit from additional memory, but the 4GB machine is preventing increased use due to Oracle or OS restrictions.  For example, the SGA size may be more restricted on the 4GB system.

If more memory is allocated to Oracle processes on 16GB machine than the 4GB machine then you should investigate the later.  If similar amounts of memory (not percentages) are allocated on each, then you should investigate the former.

Answer (score 1):

As `SYS` run `@?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt`. That will allow you to compare where machines A and B are spending the most time. There's too little to go on in your question. Are the machines, disks, Oracle versions, other workloads etc identical apart from the memory?

Or for a specific SQL_ID, use [AWR SQL report](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/performance/tips-perf-awr-sql-report-129542.pdf).

Comment: awr won't help a lot as it only shows the system performance and not the performance of individual queries. It makes more sense to trace the individual session.

Comment: the machines are same in terms of processor capacity and disk and oracle version. The workload is same across both the databases - one application runs against the database that inserts these rows. These inserts are made across multiple sessions - so tracing sessions was not helping.

Comment: i've added the trace 10046 at system level for both db's. Once the job finishes i will have more data to add

Comment: @steve correct, but there is too little to go on in the question, so that is where to start. I have updated my answer with the next step.

Comment: @praveen - multiple sessions running the same SQL? Because you can report on a SQL_ID with AWR too.