# RAM Impact on database operations

Tags: oracle, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RAM Impact on Oracle database operations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/ram-impact-on-oracle-database-operations)

We are seeing drastic change in the amount of time taken for db operations depending on ram size.

The same content when inserted into a db running on a 4gb ram machine takes about 600% more than into a db running on a 16gb ram machine. The inserts are made through jdbc. Both the db machines were 64 bit machines and both were enterprise editions of db.

Interesting thing is that the memory consumption for the db running on 4gb machine never goes above 50-60% of the total capacity - so we do not understand why this difference.
Is there any explanation for this behavior or some more pointers to look into this?

Comment: Im going to guess because with smaller space, the data in memory isnt laid out contiguous, so it has to find empty blocks.  However with very large amounts of memory, there are always large blocks of free space.

Comment: @Austin this not how oracle works

Answer (score 3):

The information you provided is not sufficient to analyze the problem, so people will start guessing (BTW how have you established your theory that the problem is memory pressure?). To analyze the problem you need to enable sql_trace for both sessions, even better set event 10046 for both sessions and then compare the data.

this can be done by executing the following sql once the session has been established

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';
```

This will generate trace files. These trace files need to be analyzed either manually or with tkprof. You need to pay attention to the wait events.

Are there any other differences between the machines in terms of

- Processor
- Disk speeds and disk types
- Network infrastructure
- Other load on the machine
- Number of database sessions

As these will affect the performance measurements

Comment: No difference is there in terms of processor (both are 64 bit machines) or disk speeds. No extra load is there on the machine other than the one application that runs those queries. So the number of sessions too are same.

Comment: i've added the trace at system level for both db's. Once the job finishes i will have more data to add